# How do you close netcat connection after receipt of data?

Tags: bash, netcat

A very simple use of `netcat` is below:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "hello world" > original.txt
base64 original.txt > encoded.txt
cat encoded.txt | nc -l -p 1234 -q 0
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh

nc localhost 1234 -q 0 > received.txt
base64 -d received.txt > decoded.txt
rm received.txt encoded.txt
echo "Sent:"
md5sum original.txt
echo "Received:"
md5sum decoded.txt
rm decoded.txt original.txt
```

This creates a file, encodes it into base64, sends it over `netcat`, and then decodes it, finally comparing whether what was sent and what was received is identical using a checksum comparison.

On a Kali Linux machine I was using earlier, the `netcat` connection closes upon execution of the second script, but trying on Ubuntu at home, this is not the case. I need to manually close the connection with `Ctrl+D`.

How can I make it such that the connection closes after receiving this data?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/512722/how-to-automatically-close-netcat-connection-after-data-is-sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think including the `-c` flag for `nc` should do it. Also, are you sure you want to use Bourne shell, and not Bash? I'd suggest changing your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`